# Help with ClamAV

Tags: clamav

I've installed ClamTK via sudo `apt-get install clamtk` then realised it's outdated and purged clamtk. Then compiled clamav from source from the latest release following the instructions [here](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Installing.md)

When I go to run `sudo freshclam` I get

```
renamon@Gibson{~/Desktop/clamav-0.98.3}:sudo freshclam
ERROR: Can't open/parse the config file /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

And `clamscan -r /` gives me

```
renamon@Gibson{~/Desktop/clamav-0.98.3}:sudo clamscan -r /
LibClamAV Error: cl_load(): No such file or directory: /usr/local/share/clamav
ERROR: Can't get file status

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 0
Engine version: 0.98.3
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
renamon@Gibson{~/Desktop/clamav-0.98.3}:
```

Any help on the issue?

Comment: Does /usr/local/share/clamav exist?

Comment: No it does not :( What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably didn't install a dependency. Lets see.

Comment: What instructions did you follow to install?

Comment: ./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

Comment: No, like the actual instructions ;) btw, what version did you install?

Comment: Clamav 0.98.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two clamav packages in Ubuntu:

- `clamav` (The virus scanner itself, with only a CLI interface)
- `clamtk` (A community build front-end for clamav)

The install `clamav` with GUI, you will need both. for the CLI only,just install `clamav`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamav
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

When the installation is finished, enter the following to update your virus DB:

```
sudo clamav clamav-freshclam
```

Optionality you can also install the clamav daemon with:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

And to also be able to scan zip files, you will need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libclamunrar6
```

**vim /etc/clamd.conf**

```
ScanArchive=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update AV databases (freshclam -v);
If you install in a None-Internet environment, Try with one that has internet capability then copy the all db files to it

```
locate daily.cvd /var/clamav/daily.cvd

ll /var/clamav total 164776 drwxr-xr-x. 3 clamav
clamav      4096 Nov 24 08:43
clamav-02eec054bbbedef0a2cfb99a9827f86e.tmp drwxr-xr-x. 3 clamav
clamav      4096 Nov 21 17:07
clamav-a17ee1dc54d880226cb90f6751692a4a.tmp srw-r--r--. 1 clamav
clamav         0 Nov 24 08:45 clmilter.socket
-rw-r--r--. 1 clamav clamav   5240725 Jun 25  2012 daily.cvd
-rw-r--r--. 1 clamav clamav 163468288 Nov 21 17:03 main.cld
-rw-------. 1 clamav clamav      1248 Nov 24 08:43 mirrors.dat
```